# My typing simulator runs in the python shell but not in real life?

Tags: python, shell

I am writing a program to simulate typing and it runs in the python shell but not when double clicked any ideas?

My code is as follows:

```
import sys,time
def slow_text(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print("")
slow_text('Hello')
```

I am using python 3.5.

Comment: The file it self may not have execute permissions

Comment: If you are "double-clicking" then that sounds like you are launching it from Windows.  Check your file associations.  That is, check that the `.py` file extension actually runs python .  If it did run then it would flash a brief console window, since you are not waiting.  Put a dummy `input()` at the end of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually calling `sys.stdout.flush`.  That line should be:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Without flushing, what's actually happening is that the script delays for some seconds with a blank console window (while the characters go into the output buffer) and then they all appear at once and the script ends and the window immediately closes, before you have a chance to see them.

That it worked in the Python shell was just a coincidence.